# Setting up Jest with Babel and Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, jestjs

I have an old angular 1 app, which uses Karma+Jasmine, and I am migrating to Webpack + React + Babel, so far so good. Now I want to switch to Jest as well. So I setup jest:

```
//package.json
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "./node_modules/babel-jest",
    "verbose": true,
    "testPathDirs": [
      "app/src"
    ],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./app/src/jest.init.js",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "./node_modules/"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "es6"]
  }
```

And my `jest.init.js` looks like:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import _ from 'lodash';
import jest from 'jest';
import io from 'socket.io';
import 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks';
import 'angular-ui-bootstrap';
import '../../build/js/main_libs';
import '../../build/js/app';
```

Where `app.js` is the compiled (from Webpack/Babel) version of my app. The problem comes with `global`. There is a function that looks like this

```
(function(global) {

    if (global._babelPolyfill) {
      throw new Error("only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed");
    }
    global._babelPolyfill = true;
}.call(exports, (function() { return this; }())
```

**I think the problem is that JEST doesnt run on the browser, so no `window` object, and `global` is undefined. Any ways to solve that? Anyone with previous experience?**